# Use a column value in an other table with laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have two table witch named users & Inbox

In the Inbox table I have a column named `sender_id` that have the `user_id` of the sender

I want to show this message in the view. I need a query to get the `sender_id` from the inbox table and use that to select a certain user from the users table 
I need to do this with all messages and all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel is basicly straith foward when you use eloquent. You can always customise it.

First, almost all the time, I create a model and a migration at the same time using this : `php artisan make:model Something --migration`

I know you already make some models and/or migrations, but I'll go step by step to help you understand it.

So, in your case, it'll be `php artisan make:model User --migration` and `php artisan make:model Inbox --migration`. Doing this, you get two model named `User` and `Inbox` and two migration named `date_create_users_table.php` and `date_create_inboxs_table.php`. Maybe you already did the default user table with `php artisan make:auth`. If it's the case, don't remake one.

I'm not sure about how laravel will name the Inbox model migration... Since, I think, Laravel 5.3, the plurialisation changed and don't always just add an "S" at the end.

Then, now you got your models and migrations, let's add some line into your migration files. Since you want to do a one to many relationship. You don't need to touch the user one. Only the Inbox migration. Each Inbox is related to one User and Users can have many Inboxs. Add something like this in your migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('inboxs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        all other columns...
    });
}
```

There, you can change the column's name if you need to have a sender, a recipient, etc... Do this instead :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('inboxs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('sender_id');
        $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('recipient_id');
        $table->foreign('recipient_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        all other columns...
    });
}
```

What we just did, it's creating the Foreign key that Laravel will use to build the query. There is one last part before the fun one. We need to create the relation in our Model. Begin with the user one:

App/User.php

```
public function inboxs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Inbox::class);
}
```

And now into the App/Inbox.php model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

If you need to have a Sender/Recipient/etc... go this way instead:

```
public function sender() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function recipient() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Note that each of your function need to be writen in the same way it's into your migration. `sender_id` need a relation named `sender()`.

Now, that our relations are done, we can simply call everything using eloquent.

```
$inboxs = Inbox::with('sender')->get();
```

This will return an array of all your Inbox into the inboxs table. You can access the sender this way: `$inboxs[0]->sender();`

You need the id, do this: `$sender_id = $inboxs[0]->sender_id;`
The sender name :  `$sender_name = $inboxs[0]->sender->name;`

If you want to get one Inbox and you have the id, just do this `$inbox = Inbox::with('sender')->find($id);`
This way you don't get an array, only one result and can access the sender directly using `$sender_name = $inbox->sender->name;` instead of having to add [0] or using a foreach loop.

You can get all messages sended by a user using something like this:

```
$inboxs = Inbox::where('sender_id', $sender_id)->get();
```

**Finally**, you can pass your data to the view using:

```
return view('path.to.view')->with('inbox',$inbox);
```

Into the view you do this to show the sender's name:

```
//If view.blade.php
{{$inbox['sender']['name']}} //work a 100%
{{$inbox->sender->name}} //I'm not sure about this one

//If not using blade
<?php echo $inbox['sender']['name']; ?>
```

There is a lot of thing you can do using Eloquent and you can add as much condition you want. The only thing I suggest you to really do if you want to use Eloquent, be aware about the n+1 problem. [There is a link where I explain it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706556/relationships-of-models-laravel-5-2/35707171#35707171). Look for the EDIT section of my answer.

If you need some documentation:
[Laravel 5.3 Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)
[Laravel 5.3 Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations)
[Laravel 5.3 Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your code like:

```
$user_messages = DB::table('messages')
                   ->select('messages.id as msgId','messages.message as message','users.id as userId','users.user_name as user_name')
                   ->join('messages','messages.user_id','=','users.id')
                   ->where('messages.user_id',$user_id)
                   ->get();

return view("view.path")
           ->with('messages',$user_messages);
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

In Model :

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Messages extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table_name';

```
public function sender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'sender_id', 'id');
}
```

}

In Controller :

public function functionName($user_id){

```
$messages = Messages::where('sender_id', $user_id)->get();

return view("view.path")
        ->with('messages',$messages);
```

}

In view, you can access seder details like this $message->sender->name for name for id $message->sender->id